# Insert/ update at the same time in a MySql table?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySql database hosted on a webserver which has a set of tables with data in it. I am distributing my front end application which is build using HTML5 / Javascript /CS3.

Now when multiple users tries to make an insert/update into one of the tables at the same time is it going to create a conflict or will it handle the locking of the table for me automatically example when one user is using, it will lock the table for him and then let the rest follow in a queue once the user finishes it will release the lock and then give it to the next in the queue ? Is this going to happen or do i need to handle the case in mysql database

EXAMPLE:

When a user wants to make an insert into the database he calls a php file located on a webserver which has an insert command to post data into the database. I am concerned if two or more people make an insert at the same time will it make the update.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO cfv_postbusupdate (BusNumber, Direction, StopNames, Status, comments, username, dayofweek, time) VALUES (".trim($busnum).", '".trim($direction3)."', '".trim($stopname3)."', '".$status."', '".$comments."', '".$username."', '".trim($dayofweek3)."', '".trim($btime3)."' )");
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by “insert/update”? Can you provide a simplified `INSERT` statement that serves as an example? What possible kind of conflict are you concerned about? Can you provide an example of such a conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL handles table locking automatically.

Note that with MyISAM engine, the entire table gets locked, and statements will block ("queue up") waiting for a lock to be released.

The InnoDB engine provides more concurrency, and can do row level locking, rather than locking the entire table.

There may be some cases where you want to take locks on multiple MyISAM tables, if you want to maintain referential integrity, for example, and you want to disallow other sessions from making changes to any of the tables while your session does its work. But, this really kills  concurrency; this should be more of an "admin" type function, not really something a concurrent application should be doing.

If you are making use of transactions (InnoDB), the issue your application needs to deal with is the sequence in which rows in which tables are locked; it's possible for an application to experience "deadlock" exceptions, when MySQL detects that there are two (or more) transactions that can't proceed because each needs to obtain locks held by the other. The only thing MySQL can do is detect that, and the only recovery MySQL can do for this is to choose one of the transactions to be the victim, that's the transaction that will get the "deadlock" exception, because MySQL killed it, to allow at least one of the transactions to proceed.